# Python does not sort sql query result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

`results = conn.execute(SEARCH_SQL, dict(fingerprint="{"+fp_str+"}")).fetchall() 
print sorted(results)`

I retrieve some datas from database by using sql alchemy. `results` is like that:

```
[(0.515625, u'str1'), (0.625, u'str2'), (0.901042, u'str3')]
```

However sort function does not work here, that is it does not do any operation on the list returned from sql query? How can I sort result list?

Comment: Question is: how would you like to sort it?

Comment: according to first key in tuples, ascending or descending, does not mather just sort. :)

Comment: Why don't you use the database to take care of sorting instead ? "ORDER BY" anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of tuples. How would you like to sort them?

For example, if you want to sort them according to the first key:

```
sorted(results, key=lambda t:t[0])
```

or in reverse order:

```
sorted(results, key=lambda t:t[0], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Ok your code worked. But in interpreter it works without 'key=lambda t:t[0]' option, why this so?

Comment: It works because by default the first part of the tuple is evaluated first.